# Как изменить поведение FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица со вторичным ключом с поведением ON DELETE SET NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE `deltas`
(
    `deltaId` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    `fwSourceId` INT UNSIGNED,
    ...

    FOREIGN KEY (fwSourceId) REFERENCES fws(fwId)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Теперь бизнес-логика немного меняется и надо сделать ON DELETE CASCADE.

Хотел просто дропнуть связь и создать новую с нужным поведением:

```
ALTER TABLE deltas DROP FOREIGN KEY fwSourceId;
```

отвечает 1091

```
Can't DROP 'fwSourceId'; check that column/key exists
```

Есть ли запрос, изменяющий поведение ON DELETE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы указали имя поля, на которое сделан внешний ключ, а нужно имя ключа

см его через information_scheema или, ёмнип, show create table `deltas`